# Unable to create Qt 5.8 kit despite having all the libraries installed

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator, qt5.8

I'm running Arch Linux, and have installed all the qt5 and qt4 libraries, alongside qtcreator. However when I go to select my qt version when creating a new project, I cannot get 5.8 to work, only 5.7. Is this a known bug, and do you have any solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide an error message when you are using qt5.8 please?

Comment: [Project setup](https://u.teknik.io/u8ZlX.png) and [kits](https://u.teknik.io/NZNcU.png). This is when selecting the min Qt version as 5.8, older versions (5.7 and below) work fine.

Comment: Have you selected the right qmake for Qt5.8 under the Qt Versions window (manage button of Qt version)? Weird, seems to be good.

Comment: Yep, everything there is pointing towards Qt 5.8.